# What makes an AMQ queue's pending message number negative？

Tags: activemq-classic

After I purged the message of a queue (not a topic), the pending message number of this queue in Active MQ Admin console changed to negative.

I assumed the pending message number of any queue ought to be positive. Is it issue of purging? Or is it a bug of activemq?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in ActiveMQ. I've personally witnessed this bug on numerous occasions when purging a queue. It does not seem to affect actual message delivery however.

There are a number of open issues in the ActiveMQ issue tracker related to this problem. You can vote them up if you want:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-3472

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-3111

Answer (score 1):

This problem is solved in ActiveMQ 5.8 :

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-4598

Answer (score 0):

Purging doesnt stop the mq from processing the queued jobs. Restart the ActiveMQ is only getting rid of the existing jobs. The down side to this is, this will make all the numbers reset to default.